# Subtract a vector across all columns in a tensor for Torch

Tags: lua, torch

Given a tensor of dimensions NxM and a vector Nx1, how do I subtract the vector in each column of the tensor in Torch?

Comment: Can you provide sample code that you have tried already?  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help in writing a question that will get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use [expand](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#expandingreplicatingsqueezing-tensors). Example:

```
local A = torch.Tensor{{1, 2},{3, 4},{5,6}}
local B = torch.ones(3)
local C = A - B:view(3, 1):expandAs(A) -- make a 3x1 tensor before expand
print(C)
--  0  1
--  2  3
--  4  5
-- [torch.DoubleTensor of size 3x2]
```